# Необходима помощь в sql запросе

Tags: php, mysql, sql, запрос

Необходимо создать фильтр в таблице по трем столбцам: обьем, высота, диаметр.
Необходимо выводить в таблице результаты максимально приближенные к значениям введенным в поля фильтра
к примеру вводим в поле обьема 5 и должно вывести обьекты с максимально близкими значениями из бд. 
Если в бд есть обьемы 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 10, 12 , то должно вывести обьекты с обьемом 3, 5, 8.

Нужна помощь хотя бы с чего начать и в каком направлении копать и возможно ли вообще такое,
 буду благодарен ссылкам.

Comment: не совсем понятно как вы хотите использовать столбцы: `высота, диаметр`...

Comment: А мне непонятно, почему 3 максимально близко к 5, а 2 -- уже нет. Видимо, предполагается какой-то параметр, который задаёт максимальный разброс значений?

Comment: @Jean-Claude Ну, гадать и я могу сколько угодно долго )) Хотелось бы услышать точное определение. Вариант с эпсилоном уже вон и в ответах фигурирует.

Comment: Вы можете дать определение для: `обьекты с максимально близкими значениями`?

Comment: @Vadim т.к. в вопросе есть метка php, оставлю этот вариант в каменте: [смотреть](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/536e014b259865fd19c1d53071912dd264447b45)

Comment: Имелось ввиду не именное 3,5,8 вывести а вывести в таким виде, что сперва меньшие значения по сравнению с заданным параметром а потом большие. извините сразу не смог сформулировать словами это, решил для наглядности изобразить итог

Comment: максимально близкое значение в вашем случае будет иметь минимальный модуль разности искомого значения и того, что в таблице. просто сделайте abs(foo - bar) и отсортируйте по этому значению.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так покажет два ближайших

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
order by abs((heght*length*width) - volume) limit 2;
```

Comment: Ошибся в порядке сортировки. теперь правильно

Answer (score 0):

Для поиска *числа*, меньшего искомого, и *числа*, большего искомого, выполним такой запросик:

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    table_name
WHERE 
    volume = (SELECT MIN(volume) FROM table_name where volume > 45) 
    OR volume = (SELECT MAX(volume) FROM table_name where volume < 45)
    OR volume = 45
```

45 - ваша цифра (введенная в поле объема)

```
//Тестовая колонка - запрос 45
29
30
31
45
46
47
//Выведет
31
45
46
```

Данный код предназначен для поиска значений объема, то есть для 3 разных колонок придется выполнить три раза - для объема, высоты, диаметра.

По мотивам https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084390/how-to-find-the-previous-and-next-record-using-a-single-query-in-mysql (ключевые слова для поиска mysql neighbor nearest)

Comment: первый результат данного запроса будет минимальным из всей таблицы. Автору нужна максимально приближенное.

Comment: вот пример для прояснения:
значение 1, 401,402 ищем по 400, 
отдает 1,401

Comment: @tcpack4 ну правильно, человеку нужна тара объемом 400, но такой нет, поэтому он может выбрать тару объемом 401 куб см, к примеру.

Comment: 401 и 402 ближайшие, но не 1.

Comment: @tcpack4 ок, обновил.

Comment: опять же, данный запрос будет брать всегда минимальные значения (т.к нет сортировки). к примеру, если там есть 395, он возьмет его, а не 402, хотя 402 ближе. Для тестов: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b900a/1

Comment: @tcpack4 угомонись, ТС уже сделал уточнение, ближайшие меньшее и большее.

Comment: данный запрос не находит ближайшее меньшее. чтобы он находил нужна сортировка. Не верите мне, вот @Lexx918 там же об этом говорит.

Comment: @tcpack4 так как ТС уточнил вопрос, второй sql автоматом я удалил.

Comment: я про второй и говорю - он не работает по условиям ТС :)

Answer (score 0):

Sql не пой профиль, но может это поможет?

```
select top 1 
    a.height
from tableA as a
where
    a.height < [ConcreteHeight]
order by a.height desc
union
select top 2 
    a.height
from tableA as a
where
    a.height >= [ConcreteHeight]
order by a.height
```

Comment: top это в mysql?

Answer (score -1):

```
 SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY ABS(height- :height)
```

где :height значение фильтра.

Comment: @Jean-Claude (height- :height) получает разницу вводимого значения со  значением в БД, ABS приводит из отрицательного в положительное и позволяет сортировать (в данном случаи только по одному полю, но позволяет и добавить другие).

Comment: 1) ок, понял вашу идею, хотя LIMIT могли бы дописать. 2) `со значением в БД` - это что такое? откуда берется этот `height`?

Comment: ТС не говорит сколько надо получать ближайших записей из бд, но раз в примере у него три значения, значит надо LIMIT 3 добавить  2) height - поле в таблице. :height это параметр с клиентской стороны (параметры принято именовать начиная с двоеточия http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: двоеточие я знаю, это вот откуда берется и почему? `ABS(height-5)` в документации такого приёма не видел.